# Unable to Merge Dex While building android in ionic 1

Tags: android, ionic-framework, gradle

I am trying to build my ionic application when the build gets started i am getting an error as follows:

```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

My Gradle Version is  4.1.0 and 
Android version is 6.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this commands**

```
cordova clean android
cordova build android
```

Comment: let me try this